# Getting post build environment variables in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When trying to add a new feature to my plugin i encountered the following issue.
The goal is to grab changes to environment variables that are overwritten during the build.
For example : A string variable (param1) that gets new value from a shell script.
So, I added the following code:

```
@Extension
public class MyRunListener extends RunListener<Run>{

    @Override
    public Environment setUpEnvironment(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, 
                     BuildListener listener) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new Environment(){
            @Override
            public boolean tearDown(AbstractBuild build, BuildListener listener) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                EnvVars envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
                String param1 = envVars.get("param1");
                return super.tearDown(build, listener);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

When running the job : param1 = defaultValue. The job then changes to : param1 = newValue.
Inside the *tearDown(…)* method I’m trying to get the new value of param1, but I get the list of variables before the changes, where *param1 = defaultValue* and not the new value that was overwritten by the shell command, where *param1 = newValue*.
Is it possible to get the new value programmatically? I know that i can write to property file and then read it, but i'm looking for "behind the stage" solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there is a method to get the current value of an environment variable is:

```
System.getProperty("param1")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeanne, but by the time jenkins calls *tearDown(...)*, the process is already closed and the property is null.

Answer (score 0):

@Moosh,

No, an environment variable cannot be passed *up* from the context of your your Java code to the Jenkins engine. As you noted, you must write it out to a file and then parse it.

Fortunately, it's not *quite* as messy as you feared. Instead of creating a separate property file, simply write the value out to Jenkins console logs, and then at the end of the run get the text of the logs via

```
$ curl http://jenkins-host/job/job-name/number/consoleText
```

Hope that helps.